# Office 365 Graph API Reporting getOneDriveActivityFileCounts or GetEmailActivityCounts gives error

Tags: office365, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to pull some reports from O365 using graph API, the examples work and graph explorer works as well, but when trying to pull any report that returns a CSV or text file I get errors, I am using the following core:

```
  IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create("XXX")
            .Build();
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "Organization.ReadWrite.All",
        "Reports.Read.All" };
            var accounts = await publicClientApplication.GetAccountsAsync();
            AuthenticationResult result;
            try
            {
                result = await publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                            .ExecuteAsync();
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
            {
                result = await publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                            .ExecuteAsync();
            }

            // Create an authentication provider by passing in a client application and graph scopes.
            DeviceCodeProvider authProvider = new DeviceCodeProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);
            // Create a new instance of GraphServiceClient with the authentication provider.
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
            var x = await graphClient.Reports.GetOneDriveActivityFileCounts("D30").Request().GetAsync()
```

;

this gives an error:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: R. Path '', line 0, position 0.'

From the documentation this should return a URL where I can download the file, I tried to request a JSON format but it is not supported as well, what am I doing wrong ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);`, it will give this error.

Digging into the SDK, I found that there is a `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Report>(inputString)` method under HttpProvider.

Here is its information:

```
/// <summary>
/// Deserializes the JSON string to an object of the specified type.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The deserialization type.</typeparam>
/// <param name="inputString">The JSON string to deserialize.</param>
/// <returns>The deserialized object.</returns>
    T DeserializeObject<T>(string inputString);
```

Obviously this is the cause of the error. It can't be deserialized because it's CSV rather than JSON data.

I think it's a bug of Graph SDK currently.

As a workaround, you can directly call the API endpoint to get the data.

Or you could implement your own Serializer in your code.

See the following sample:

```
HttpProvider provider = new HttpProvider(new MySerializer());
var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider, provider);
var x = await graphClient.Reports.GetOneDriveActivityFileCounts("D30").Request().GetAsync();
```

And MySerializer() is like this:

```
internal class MySerializer : ISerializer
        {
            public T DeserializeObject<T>(Stream stream)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }



            public T DeserializeObject<T>(string inputString)
            {

                //implement your logical here 
                return default(T);
            }



            public string SerializeObject(object serializeableObject)
            {
                //implement your logical here 
                return "TEST MESSAGE";
            }
        }
```

The `inputString` is the content of the csv report. You could handle it by yourself. And then it will return to the "x" you defined.

Comment: Worked amazingly, yet I have a small glitch

the report is passed through 
            return default(T);

and it returns default, but this apparently breaks the code as x becomes null, although it should imputstring has already the report value, not sure why

Answer (score 1):

As of Sept 2020, one option is to use the [beta sdk](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Beta) which allows you to request for [json payload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getonedriveactivityfilecounts?view=graph-rest-beta#json).The call would then look like this

```
var options = new List<QueryOption>()
{
    new QueryOption("format", "application/json")
};
var x = graphClient.Reports.GetEmailActivityCounts("D7").Request(options).GetAsync().Result;
```

Reference:

- [Providing custom parameters for msgraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-requests?tabs=CS#provide-custom-query-parameters)
- Using the beta sdk in dot net core.

> dotnet add package Microsoft.Graph.Beta